# WFFM Form Designer - Cannot update existing checkbox list parameters

Tags: wffm

I have a checkbox List field and need to add and change a few options but unable to as we do not see them in Form Designer.  When I look at the item in Content Editor, I can view the values however are not in an easily editable format.  See attached images as supporting doc.

We are on Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160304

Thanks in advance

Screen 1 shows Parameters in content Editor
[image]

Screen 2 I would expect to see parameters here.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your issue? The forms designer is a user friendly (well, an attempt of) way to edit the data that you can find in the fields in the content editor.. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We are trying to change an option but as the screens show (which I just updated for clarity) you cannot see the existing options.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue for a drop list field after upgrading to SC 8.2 Update 3 using the Sitecore Content Migration tool.

I fixed this issue copying the Parameters field values in the Localized Parameters field. After this I was able to see and edit the options in the Form Designer again.